# Django celery is not processing the task

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I am trying to tigger a process that runs in the background. I am calling this process using ajax call.
I have setup celery/rabbitmq/flower to achieve this.
In my app ->views.py

```
def sync_now(request,sync_id):
    sync_obj=Sync.objects.get(id=sync_id)
   
    synchronize_data.apply_async(args=[sync_id])
    result = synchronize_data.apply_async(args=[sync_id])
    # Get the task ID
    task_id = result.id
    print("task id")
    return render something
```

Tasks.py
app = Celery('sync', broker='pyamqp://xxx:xxxx@localhost:5672/myvhost')

```
@shared_task
def synchronize_data(sync_id):
    try:
        sync_obj = Sync.objects.get(id=sync_id)
        # Your synchronization logic goes here
        sync_data(sync_id, sync_obj)
        return 'Success'  # Return a result to indicate success
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)  # Return an error message in case of failure
```

When I run this command -
`celery -A ipass worker -l info --pool=solo --` it appears like all the queued process gets triggered and sync_data is called multiple times. I had to manually kill the cmd

But when I trigger this from the template I get only

```
[2023-08-26 23:08:26,320: INFO/MainProcess] Task sync.tasks.synchronize_data[0c72b00b-acf1-48d2-ab44-6ddb678d62e8] received
[2023-08-26 23:08:26,320: INFO/MainProcess] Task sync.tasks.synchronize_data[7c2c018f-cd6b-4dae-8cab-b18a572a5c92] received
[2023-08-26 23:08:26,887: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-32] child process 10588 calling self.run()
[2023-08-26 23:08:26,888: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-33] child process 11024 calling self.run()
```

I am unable to debug, what is missing here ? Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I recommend creating a separate Django project to see if you can reproduce the behavior you are asking about. Keep it as simple as you can. If you get the same problem and still can't figure out why, then post your complete code here.